# Why does Yii add an extra period to email address when creating a URL

Tags: php, yii

[image]

How its possible in Yii, framework added 2 dot to url get parametr O_o
Here is code:

```
<strong>
<?php 
echo $mails;
?>
<p>
    Добро пожаловать в интернет-магазин <?php echo Yii::app()->params['nameProject'].", ".$name; ?>
    <p>Для продолжения регистрации подтвердите свой электронный адрес - <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/verification', array('code' => $md5, 'mail' => $mails));?>">Подтвердить</a></p>
    <p>
        С уважением и пожеланием успехов, команда <?php echo Yii::app()->params['nameProject']; ?>!
    </p>
</p>
</strong>
```

**UPDATE1: answet to comment**

> Blockquote

Sure, i am atach photo and code, you can see, that i am print $mails which is = `arthur952010@gmal.com`, so also you are can see url parametr `arthur952010@gmal..com`. Where if appear two dots? Need to be one, when i am call `<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/verification', array('code' => $md5, 'mail' => $mails));?>`

Comment: Your question title is quite weird. Could you clarify in text what you are wondering about if it's possible?

Comment: Sure, i am atach photo and code, you can see, that i am print $mails which is = `arthur952010@gmal.com`, so also you are can see url parametr `arthur952010@gmal..com`. Where if appear two dots? Need to be one, when i am call `<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/verification', array('code' => $md5, 'mail' => $mails));?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL encode the email address manually:

```
<a href="<?= Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(
    'site/verification', array('code' => $md5));
    ?>&mail=<?= urlencode($mails) ?>">Подтвердить</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Yii, but with a miscommunication between swiftmailer (yii's default email library) and one of the other components in your email stack such as postfix or nullmailer.

The SMTP protocol specifies that a line starting with a period has a special meaning. To work around that, nullmailer by default escapes lines starting with a period with an extra period. However, the transport you use to actually deliver the email might do exactly the same thing, causing the period to be escaped twice, causing a double period in the end result.

Using this config for swiftmailer fixed it for me:

```
'mailer'        => [
    'class'     => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'transport' => [
        'class'     => 'Swift_SendmailTransport',
        'command'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
    ]
],
```

References:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.2
- http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-sendmail-transport
- https://encrypted.google.com/#q=swiftmailer+double+dot